# Install MacOS Sierra

Tags: mac, macos, install

I have formatted my MacBook Air and I am trying to install macOS Sierra which is taking a lot of time and is consuming a lot of data(connected via mobile hotspot).

Is there any way that I can install it through bootable pen-drive or the other way?

On finding it over the Internet, it says to mount it on a USB and then open Terminal and type some commands, but I can't use Terminal as I've already formatted the disk and on booting up the device it shows 4 options as in given [here](https://www.lifewire.com/thmb/xSB1fRLwrRE511ZQMBC25K5nbOI=/2048x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/macOSUtilities-5783e90b5f9b5831b5d21eb2.jpg).

So, the above way doesn't work for me.

Apple users are very few. Any other user is available! How can I download the installer from other PC. Is there any link ?

Comment: yes it is possible, do you have a bootable pen-drive ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 question edited

Comment: well, you re out of luck then unless you have a friend to do it for you, or just wait till the download/install is completed.

Comment: Well, I can download whatever you say from another PC. Downloading and installing the OS is  a problem in just my PC.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you get access to another working Mac? It will make it very easy to download the installer and create a bootable USB drive. You can easily get it done at an Apple Retail Store too if you can visit one.

Comment: Apple users are very few. Any other user is available !!

Comment: How can I download the installer from other PC. Is there any link ?

Comment: The macOS installer is only available legally (and safely) from a Mac using the Apple Store. Or you could go to an Apple Store or even an Apple Authorized Service provider with your Mac and a thumb drive and Apple will provide it for free. An AASP might charge you a nominal fee.

Comment: Nothing that we say here will solve your problem with slow Internet `connected via mobile hotspot`

Comment: If you somehow could manage to get the full installer (aka install assistant) onto a USB drive, you can access Terminal in Internet Recovery (and Recovery) under the "Utilities" menu.  You could then create the installer thumb drive there.  But without installer that's a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I download the installer from other PC. Is there any link?

Officially?  No.

OS X/macOS is provided **at no cost** (to the contrary, it's not "free") to customers who own a qualifying Apple computer.  They do not make it available for download like CentOS or Ubuntu makes their distribution available "free of charge."

As such, Apple has made it so that the installer can only be downloaded to a Mac in Recovery Mode or via the App Store.

So, right now, you have but one (proper) method to install macOS - install it via Recovery.

#### Looking back....

> I have formatted my MacBook Air....

<sup>(This is intended to be a note of caution)</sup>

Before you did this, you should have at least had:

- A Time Machine backup of your existing installation/data
- A full and thorough understanding of the procedure to (re)install/upgrade macOS
- The necessary tools (i.e. the bootable USB)

There are countless problems that can be fixed with the phrase "restore from backup" and this, too is one of them.

#### Looking forward...

> Is there any way that I can install it through bootable pen-drive or the other way?

There's only one "proper" method, and that's to obtain it from Apple (via Recovery, App Store or even a friend/colleague who owns an Apple.)  Short of that, you are left with questionable (at best) solutions for this - download a USB image from a Torrent (I'm not listing any here).

Obviously, you can do this from a PC running Windows or Linux, but you need the USB image because you will have very little success converting an ISO (CD/DVD image) to a USB image (.img).

You can create image using `dd` (assuming you're on Linux) with this simple command:

```
$ dd if=/path/to/usbimage.img of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

Obviously, you want to change the filename of the image and the output device (`of=`) to their appropriate and respective values.

Now, here's the key.  Once you have it installed, download a legitimate copy from App Store.  Create a *new* USB installer on a *different* USB and do the whole process all over again.  If it fails, you have the first "torrented" USB image from which to work from again.  If not, you will now have the ability to create a legitimate  macOS installation.

Comment: I can download the installer in my friend's mac then what to do after that ?

Comment: Create the USB installer, then install macOS on your Mac.